# Proof of the Whitney embedding theorem for compact manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

> **I'm trying to understand Lee's proof of the Whitney embedding theorem, and there's one difficulty I fail to overcome. Please help me out. Thank you.**

[image]
[image]

> **I'm talking about the statement circled in red ink. I got that each $d(\rho_i\varphi_i)_p$ is injective but didn't see how injectivity of $dF_p$ follows easily. Did I miss any tricks?**

Comment: If you draw the matrix associated to the map , you can see that you only need that one of the $p_i\phi_i$ needs to be injective.

Comment: I just realized that I made a stupid mistake. Thanks a lot.